# Do the hspace and wspace arguments actually work in matplotlib subfigures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to insert vertical and horizontal spaces between subfigures created using [`matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures). As the documentation states, the keyword arguments to use for this are `wspace` and `hspace`.

So, let us try to use this using a simple piece of code -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

# Split figure into two subfigures and add a width-space argument
subFig = fig.subfigures(1, 2, wspace=0.5)

axs = subFig[0].subplots(2, 1)
axs = subFig[1].subplots(1, 1)

subFig[0].set_facecolor('c')
subFig[1].set_facecolor('m')

plt.show()
```

Which generates this figure -
[image: subfigure-with-wspace]

As you can see, there is no space between the two subfigures. Here is another figure with `wspace=0.`, which looks the same.

[image: subfigure-without-wspace]

Am I doing something wrong, and if so, can I fix it without using `GridSpec`?

I followed instructions as per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html), simplifying it to the short piece of the code you see here. One difference between the tutorial and what I have here is that I am not using `layout='constrained'`. In my actual code, I have several custom `Axes` that I am adding later on top of the subfigures. The addition of this new axes is abstracted one level down and hidden from the user. Using `layout='constrained'` messed up the placement of these custom axes and so I would prefer not using it.

Regardless, all I would like is for the code to work as intended in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25511) in matplotlib < 3.7.2. With v3.7.2 I do see a gap with `wspace=0.5`:

[image]

So the solution is to update matplotlib:

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```